# Trying to stop opening webservice in Design View in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, netbeans-7

In NETBEANS, every time i click on a WebService class in my code, it opens up in **design view**. I would like per default, for the class to open up in **source view**.

It is very frustrating and annoying to have to click on

is there anyway to configure this?

Comment: I was unable to replicate the Design view in netbeans 7.3. I tried opening up "Web Service Client" and a "RESTFUL Java Client" from the Web Services category, and they all opened in Source view.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have resolved itself. If I switch a Webservice to Source view, then when I switch back to it, it remembers it needs to be in source view. I don't know why its working now. .... oh well.